# How to Mock deleting an item in the test using react testing library?

Tags: graphql, react-testing-library

i want to delete an item on clicking  delete button. How can i mock the delete item using react-testing library

I have the delete button like below,

```
function SomeComponent () {
    const { deleteItem } = useDeleteItem();
    render = () => {
        return (
            <Menu
                id={Item.id}
                onClick={() => deleteItem({ id: Item.id })}
                data-test-id={`test-${Item.id}`}
             >
                 Delete
             </Menu>

         )
     }
```

within my tests i do something like below,

```
const items: Items[] = [
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'somename',
    }
    {
        id: '2';
        name: 'other',
     }
];  


const deleteItem: {
    id: '1',
    name:'somename',
}


test('remove an item', async () => {
    const { getByTestId } = utils.render(
        <SomeComponent openByDefault />,
        [
            utils.gqlMock(LIST_ITEMS, items),
            utils.gqlMock(DELETE_ITEM, deleteItem,
            {id: Item.id}), //this should be called after clicking test- 
            delete-1 element but it doesnt as i get timedout error for 
            //domchange
            utils.gqlMock(LIST_ITEMS, [..items, deleteItem]),
        ]
    );
    utils.fireEvent.click(getByTestId("test-delete-1"));
    await utils.waitForDomChange(); //it throws error here timedout 
    expect(getByTestId("test-delete-1").toBeNull();
)
```

After clicking delete button i want the item to be deleted. so i check for delete element to be null.

But this test fails...as this delete element is still visible.

Could someone tell me how to mock delete item here. Thanks.

Comment: Without seeing all your code, do you expect the button to be deleted (what you're testing) or some item (like in the items array) to be removed?

Comment: i expect the item to be deleted

Comment: each item has it s own delete button.

Comment: What does your SomeComponent look like?

Comment: updated the question.